Discover won't launch
I have a recent install of UbuntuStudio 24.04. After working for a day or so, now Discover won't launch. It looks to me like it is this bug with Plasma 5.27:
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=481993
If it is that, the bug is fixed in Plasma 6 but 'unlikely' to be fixed in 5.27.
What to do? How can I run updates and install new software without Discover?
For context: I'm only an average user, I prefer using gui tools, although I don't mind doing simple things in the terminal :)

What error message do you get when you run discover in the terminal?

You are not using neon 6. The bug is most likely a different one

There is no error message. It either hangs on a blank screen forever in the terminal, or reports fetch ratings! true adding empty sources model QStandardItemModel(0x6383a13ac6f0)  and then hangs forever. The behaviour overall is very similar to that reported in that thread, despite relating to a different distro.

Similar problem reported here https://discuss.kde.org/t/discover-not-working-on-kubuntu-24-04/16078/32

Rephrasing the question: how can I use this computer without Discover, while I wait for this to be fixed?

how can I use this computer without Discover -- You can install another app store, gnome-software, with sudo apt install gnome-software

Ah, right, I'm going to close this, as it is a 'known problem' that is in the release notes https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-24-04-lts-release-notes/

Here's the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plasma-discover/+bug/2063353

This is a known issue anounced in the Release Notes. You should be able to run Discover once after a boot. Also you can try to quit all instances of Discover via System Monitor > Applications and then run plasma-discover --backends kns-backend,snap-backend,packagekit-backend from terminal, I use this as a workaround when I don't want to reboot.

Known problem in the release notes for Ubuntu Studio:
https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-24-04-lts-release-notes/
Bug is here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plasma-discover/+bug/2063353
